# Google Sheets spreading cost over columns and summing

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have in Google Sheets:

```
  Price per month: $9
  Number of months: 3 (each subscription lasts 3 months)
```

Number of subscriptions per month.  (A = month 1, B = month2…)

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  0  3  0  2
```

I’d like to create some routine that will sum the total cost per month.

```
Month 1 = 9.
Month 2 = 9.
Month 3 = 9 + (3*9).
Month 4 = (3*9)  (since the subscription from Month 1 is not expired)
Month 5 = (3*9) + (2*9)
```

Is this possible?  Ideally, months would be in columns.

So my results would be:

```
A   B   C   D   E
9   9   36  27  45
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.   Month 1's subscription only impacts month 1/2/3.  Not month 4.

Comment: If subscriptions last 3 months, then subscription #1 is for Months 1,2 & 3. It will have ended by Month 4.  Month 4 is (3*9) because there are 3 subscriptions that start in Month 3 (that are in their second month in month-4).

Comment: Shit :)   But you get what I am trying to do??

Answer (score 1):

You just seem to need a three-month running total and a multiplier. In C3 and copied down:

```
=sum(B1:B3)*$A$2
```

Ensure the C1:C2 cells do not contain anything that would be taken as a number.

[image: WA10937 example]

Comment: YES.  That is EXACTLY what I need except that if my number of months changes from 3 to 4, my equation has to change to "=sum(B1:B4)'.  Hence my question.

Comment: Maybe something like: =sum(B1:B(1+n)) (where "n" is the number of months)?

Comment: Try `=sum(indirect("B1:B"&(1+n)))` then.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for catching that, and good point about the transition.